# SpriteKit Liquid Threshold Filter Effect

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

I want to create a liquid effect in SpriteKit with Objective-C.
At First I created a white blurred ball texture for the SKSpriteNode. 
Currently I am using the CIFilter "CIColorPosterize" as filter for the Threshold effect.

```
CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorPosterize"];
[filter setValue:@(2.0) forKey:@"inputLevels"];
[self.scene setFilter:filter];
[self.scene setShouldEnableEffects:YES];
```

And it looks okay: [Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVziQ.jpg)

But now I want to change the color of the balls with the colorBlendFactor.

```
ball.color = [UIColor orangeColor];
ball.colorBlendFactor = 1.0;
```

This looks not correctly for me because the CIFilter manipulates also the blend color, but without filter I haven't the Threshold effect.

Now my question: Is there a way to have the Threshold effect without changing the color?